# Foreach cannot operate on a 'method group' while iterating json array?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a json as shown below -

```
   "thothTest":{
      "9876":[
         "K"
      ],
      "5431":[
         "A",
         "L"
      ],
      "5123":[
         "L"
      ]
   }
```

This is how I get `thothTest` value. Now I am trying to print each key and their values by iterating json array. Like I want to print `9876` and its whole array by iterating it over them. Similarly for other entries.

```
var parsedthothTests = parsed["thothTest"];
foreach (var parsedthothTest in parsedthothTests)
{
    Console.WriteLine(parsedthothTest); // this prints innermost array one by one
    foreach (var val in parsedthothTest.Values)
    {

    }
}
```

In my innermost foreach loop it gives me error as - `Foreach cannot operate on a 'method group'. Did you intend to invoke the 'method group'?` What is wrong I am doing here?

Comment: When posting snippets of code, it helps to not use `var` unless the type is obvious - `var i = 0` is fine, `var x = arr[y]` it is impossible to know what `x` is, and the errors in this question relate to the type of `x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `.Values` is a method, not a property.

You should add parenthesis to invoke it.

```
foreach (var val in parsedthothTest.Values())
{
}
```

Comment: Aah I got it now. Also how can I get the value of the `key` like 9876. That foreach will iterate array and give access to each value in that array.

Comment: Probably best to ask a new question and post a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), someone will be able to run it and figure it out, without knowing the types involved it is hard to say.

Comment: Its a Jtoken. I just debugged it.